# Selenium(PYTHON) add variable that converts number into syntax

Tags: python, html, selenium, webautomation, webbot

So i have a code that changes the text of a class, but instead of manually entering the number, i would like the number to be equal to whatever X is, and convert that number into a string if thats what needs to be done

```
try:
    
newButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "btn-full")))
```

finally:

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].innerHTML = "X";', newButton)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class','NEWBUTTON')", newButton)
```

How do i make sure its made in such a way that it takes a variable that holds an integer value, and its written out in place of the X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can pass it as `arguments[1]` like this:

```
x = #some number
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].innerHTML = arguments[1];', newButton, x)
```

If you want it to be an `int` you can leave it as it is, but if you want it as a `string` then just convert it wherever you want and pass it into the method.

The `arguments[n]` is the (n+2)'nd argument you pass into the method `execute_script()`.

Comment: You could mark the answer as verified if it worked. Thank you.